# issue with socket.io client connecting multiple times [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

import '../../config.dart';
import '../showSnack.dart';

class DataStreamBloc {
  final _stateStreamController = StreamController<Map>();

  StreamSink<Map> get dataSink => _stateStreamController.sink;
  Stream<Map> get dataStream => _stateStreamController.stream;
}

StreamController<Map> controller = StreamController<Map>.broadcast();
Stream stream = controller.stream;

final dataStreamBloc = DataStreamBloc();
registerToken(context) async {
  var token = await readToken();

  if (token.isNotEmpty) {
    Socket socket = io(
'http://localhost:4400/api/ws'
       ,
        OptionBuilder()
            //  .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .enableReconnection()
            .enableAutoConnect() // disable auto-connection
            .setQuery({'token': '$token'})
            .disableForceNew()
            .disableForceNewConnection()
            .disableMultiplex()
            .setReconnectionDelay(10) // optional
            .build());
    print(socket.connected);
    if (socket.connected == false) {
      socket.connect();
    }

    socket.on('fromServer', (data) {
      print('fromServer: ' + data.toString());
    });
    socket.on('serverData', (data) {
      if (data.runtimeType.toString() == 'String') {
        var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(data.toString());
        Map dataMapped = json.decode(dataDecoded);
        var type = dataMapped['type'];
        var from = dataMapped['from'];
        var task = dataMapped['task'];

        print(dataMapped['task']);
        print(dataMapped);
        dataStreamBloc.dataSink.add(dataMapped);
        controller.add(dataMapped);
        if (type == "sessionRequest") {
          showSnack(context, 'Do you wish to accept a call from $from?');
        }
        if (type == "message") {
          showSnack(context, 'new message from $from');
        }

        return data;
      }
    });
  } else {
    print('token is missing, ask the user to log back in again');
  }
}
```

I am using getToken(context) within an init state to call socket.io, client seems to connect multiple times and that is what is causing a repeat of the information being received, on the server side I use the token to auth them and put them inside of a channel where I can then broadcast to that channel for any updates that the server has for a client. I am using socket.io for notifications and chat request. I know it is on the client side because on there server it only shows the broadcast function getting hit once. How do I make sure that this client only connects when there is not an active socket.io stream already connected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. When I was making a user offline and making it back to online socket was connected multiple time.

I just did was disposed the socket.

```
goOffline(){
socket.dispose();
}
```